# Display MD5 hashed passwords as asterisked text

Tags: php

I want to `echo` account details of users, which is fine for plain text but I have md5 hashed passwords in the database. I would like to display the password in asterisks so the only variable would be the length of the the password. So if someones password was `cat` it would show: Password: `***`   and if someone else's was `hippopotamus` it would 
show: Password: `************`  however with the password encrypted this seems difficult. although websites like eBay and Facebook do have this and they must encrypt users passwords.

can anyone shed any light on this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible. There is no way to tell the length of the input data that was used to generate an md5 hash.

> websites like ebay and facebook do have this and they must encrypt users passwords

If they do (and I hope they don't as it would leak data about the password to the public, making it much easier to crack), then they would have to store the length of the input string as well as the hashed password.

It is possible that what you are seeing is the browser auto-filling the password field for you. The asterisks being the standard masking character used (by browsers) to reduce the effectiveness of "peeking over the shoulder" attacks.

Comment: so how do other websites do  it, don't they encrypt passwords?

Comment: @user1482784 hopefully no websites encrypt passwords, there is absolutely no reason to encrypt a user's password for login purposes.  The only reason to encrypt a password is if your application needs to use it to access another service and you have the user's permission to do so.  This is insecure, and to emphasize what Quentin said again, **Showing the length of a user's password is a security leak**.  I would not appreciate it if someone did that to my password.

Comment: @user1482784 If a site shows a password field populated with non-data, convention routed back in the sands of time dictates you would show 8 characters. If you are seeing a string that actually shows the correct length of the password chances are the browser is populating the field from it's own password manager, and if you examined the source HTML you would find that the associated `<input>` would have a missing or empty `value=` attribute.

Comment: your right, it is just a standard 8 *'s it was just a coincidence that my password was also 8 so I assumed it knew, thanks for clearing that up DaveRandom, you saved me alot of unnecessary coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just store the length of the password in the database when it is intitially hashed/salted.  **BUT** the whole point of hashing/salting is to prevent the password from being compromised if the db is stolen. If the db is stolen, knowing the length of the password  is a great security compromise.

Comment: Yeah I think your right about that, better not risk it. Thanks